# Named service factory for .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, inversion-of-control, factory-pattern

I am trying to build a service factory extension method that mirrors the functionality of the popular "HttpClientFactory" within the context of a blazor client application. I want to register the same interface/class pair with a string name multiple times with different configurations. Essentially, I want to avoid making another interface or class but I want the properties of the class to be different and accessible via a factory pattern.

I would ideally like my code to look like this for registration

```
Program.cs

builder.Services.AddFoodFactory<IFoodService,FoodService>("Citrus", serviceConfig =>
   serviceConfig.StorageRoom = "A1"
)

builder.Services.AddFoodFactory<IFoodService,FoodService>("Starch", serviceConfig =>
   serviceConfig.StorageRoom = "A2"
)
```

And then use the service like so.

```
index.razor
@inject FoodServiceFactory;


   CitrusService = FoodServiceFactory.Create("Citrus");
   StarchService = FoodServiceFactory.Create("Starch");

   CitrusService.GetRoom();
   StarchService.GetRoom();
```

Currently I think this is a multiple part problem but without knowing how to begin with setting up  a way to first register the services I feel a little lost. Tim Corey did an excellent video with a factory that looks like this

```
using FactoryPattern.Samples;

namespace FactoryPattern.Factories;

public static class DifferentImplementationsFactoryExtension
{
    public static void AddVehicleFactory(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IVehicle, Car>();
        services.AddTransient<IVehicle, Truck>();
        services.AddTransient<IVehicle, Van>();
        services.AddSingleton<Func<IEnumerable<IVehicle>>>
            (x => () => x.GetService<IEnumerable<IVehicle>>()!);
        services.AddSingleton<IVehicleFactory, VehicleFactory>();
    }
}

public interface IVehicleFactory
{
    IVehicle Create(string name);
}

public class VehicleFactory : IVehicleFactory
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<IVehicle>> _factory;

    public VehicleFactory(Func<IEnumerable<IVehicle>> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IVehicle Create(string name)
    {
        var set = _factory();
        IVehicle output = set.Where(x => x.VehicleType == name).First();
        return output;
    }
}
```

However, needing different classes defeats the first problem. My instinct is to drill into making a custom "AddTransient"/"AddScoped" etc. extension method but without guidance I am hesitant to start.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.